# How to hand over a json resource policy file in aws-cli create gateway command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

How to hand over a json resource policy file in AWS CLI `create-gateway` command? In this AWS link, it is described how the json itself is passed with the command: [Create and Attach an API Gateway Resource Policy to an API - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html)

However, it is cleaner to pass the policy in a file and I tried the following:

```
aws apigateway create-rest-api \
    --name "api-name" \
    --policy "file:PolicyDocument.json"
```

Here is the `PolicyDocument.json` that is valid when I copy it via Management Console in the resource policies of the API gateway:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "execute-api:/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "100.101.102.103/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It returned the following error:

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateRestApi
>   operation: Invalid policy document. Please check the policy syntax and
>   ensure that Principals are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like for that CLI command it expects a string value 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-rest-api.html

> --policy (string) A stringified JSON policy document that applies to this RestApi regardless of the caller and Method configuration.

I was able to do this with this syntax:

`aws apigateway create-rest-api --name 'My First API' --description 'This is my first API' --policy '{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":"*","Action":"execute-api:Invoke","Resource":"execute-api:/*","Condition":{"IpAddress":{"aws:SourceIp":["100.101.102.103/32"]}}}]}'`

**OUTPUT**:

```
{
    "id": "1122334455",
    "name": "My First API",
    "description": "This is my first API",
    "createdDate": 1561818588,
    "apiKeySource": "HEADER",
    "endpointConfiguration": {
        "types": [
            "EDGE"
        ]
    },
    "policy": "{\\\"Version\\\":\\\"2012-10-17\\\",\\\"Statement\\\":[{\\\"Effect\\\":\\\"Allow\\\",\\\"Principal\\\":\\\"*\\\",\\\"Action\\\":\\\"execute-api:Invoke\\\",\\\"Resource\\\":\\\"arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:111122223333:91co7q5lj0\\/*\\\",\\\"Condition\\\":{\\\"IpAddress\\\":{\\\"aws:SourceIp\\\":\\\"100.101.102.103\\/32\\\"}}}]}"
}
```

So the JSON string will need to have it's breaklines and spaces removed in the command. I used this online tool to minify the JSON. 
https://www.browserling.com/tools/json-minify

You should also be able to minify the json using this command as well.

`cat PolicyDocument.json | jq -c`

```
{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":"*","Action":"execute-api:Invoke","Resource":"execute-api:/*","Condition":{"IpAddress":{"aws:SourceIp":["100.101.102.103/32"]}}}]}
```

**EDIT**
I just found out that this works as well:

`aws apigateway create-rest-api --name 'My First API' --description 'This is my first API' --policy file://PolicyDocument.json`

we just needed a `//` in front of the path

Comment: thanks looks great but how to pass the json not as a sting but as a file direction e.g.: `--policy "file:PolicyDocument.json"`. If there will be a lot of policies and automated then it will be messy. Other `aws-cli` commands provide this functionality.

Comment: I just executed this and it seem to work too

`aws apigateway create-rest-api --name 'My First API' --description 'This is my first API' --policy file://PolicyDocument.json`

so the syntax would go like `file://PATH_TO_FILE`